# hapijs with socket.io the right way?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, hapi.js

I'm trying to use hapijs with socket.io and already searched a lot about how to integrate socket.io into the hapi server the right way. One approach, I found, is this [example](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/11/phonestagram-fun-with-photo-filters-using-node-hapi-and-camanjs.html) and I'm still not sure if this is the way to go. I have to admit that I'm new to hapijs and I'm still learning it :)

```
var Path = require('path');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({port: 3000});

server.register(require('vision'), function (err) {
    server.views({
        engines: {
            ejs: require('ejs')
        },
        relativeTo: __dirname,
        path: 'templates'
    });
});

var plugins = [
    {register: require('./lib/index.js')}
];

server.register(plugins, function (err) {
    server.start(function () {
        io = socketio.listen(server.listener);

        io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('create', function (room) {
                socket.join(room);
                console.log("Joined room: " + room);
                socket.emit('message', "Joined room");
            });
        });
        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

And the **lib/index.js**

```
exports.register = function(server, options, next) {
    var tasks = [];

    server.route([
        {
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/tasks',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                reply.view('index', { sid: "6001" });
                io.emit('message', "Test");
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/tasks/{name}',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                reply.view('index', { sid: "6001" });
                io.emit('message', "Test");
            }
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/tasks',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                io.emit('message', "Test");
            }
        }
    ]);

    next();
}

exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'routes-tasks',
    version: '1.0.0'
};
```

Please correct me if this is not the way how to use hapijs.

Comment: Should I use [nes](https://github.com/hapijs/nes) instead of socket.io?

Answer (score 1):

you are near to it.
1)on disconnect close the sockets

```
socket.disconnect('unauthorized'); or socket.close();
```

2)use auth for every subscription

```
{
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/tasks/{name}',
           auth: auth,
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                reply.view('index', { sid: "6001" });
                io.emit('message', "Test");
            }
        },
```

3)must important thing is use Access-Control-Allow-Origin otherwise websocket hijacking will happen.

```
request.response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'your domain')
```

if you need further info let me know.I am happy to help